# How do I define my CSS to display 'HelveticaNeue-Light' using Pixate Framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, pixate

Clearification! This question is about the iOS framework Pixate (http://www.pixate.com), and not regular CSS inside of a UIWebView.

Code in default.css :

```
.title {
 font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
 font-weight: light;
 font-size: 30px;
 color: #005284;
```

}

Code in view:

```
UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
label.styleClass = @"title";
```

Result when logging:

```
<UICTFont: 0x10d09e210> font-family: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 30.00pt
```

When I try `font-weight: medium;` I get `HelveticaNeue-Medium`
When I try `font-weight: 300;` I get `HelveticaNeue-UltraLight`
When I try `font-weight: 400;` I get `Helvetica Neue`
When I try `font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light';` I get `.HelveticaNeueInterface-M3` ??? (I guess this is the default system font)

If I set the font  through code with

```
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:30];
```

It looks as it should, (and the log says `HelveticaNeue-Light`)

Here a screenshot. The one of the left is when using code, and the one on the right is when using Pixate with `font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light'

[image]

How do I get 'HelveticaNeue-Light' (like the one on the left in the screenshot above) using Pixate CSS ?

Comment: do you even have the files on your machine? need way more info than that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You found a bug in Pixate and it has been fixed for Pixate Framework 2.1.

Answer (score 6):

This works on Mavericks and my iOS 7 simulator. Don't know about others.

```
.title {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #005284;
}
```

Here is my test code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.first {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #005284;
}
.second {
    font-family: 'Helvetica';
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #005284;
}
</style>
</head>
<div class="first">Hello, World!</div>
<div class="second">Hello, World!</div>
</html>
```

And the result in Safari http://s.swic.name/TpEP

Comment: Are you sure that you get the Helvetica Neue Light ? What does is say when your log the label.font ?

Comment: Ill check but i compared side by side with a div with 'Helvetica' and it was half the weight.

Comment: A div ? What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, my question was unclear. It is now updated. The question regards to the iOS framework Pixate, and not regular CSS in a Web View.

Comment: Oh, i thought Pixelate was some HTML/CSS stuff.

Comment: Nope, It's CSS/iOS-Native stuff :)